# Retrieving the released attributes from CAS 5.0.x in Spring Security 3.2.5

Tags: java, spring-security, cas

I have already figured out how to configure the CAS 5.0.2 server to release the attributes from a JDBC source. I also have started configuring my Spring application which utilizes Spring Security 3.2.5 to intergrate CAS authentication, following the standard procedure from the docs. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve the released attributes from the CAS server after successfully authenticating against it. Are there any clean or standard way/s that the application can fetch the released attributes?